# How to parse radiobutton value in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a radioButton with conditional panels for each choice as shown below:

```
radioButtons("map_subset",label="enter choices or upload your own subset?",
                    choices=c("enter","upload"),selected="enter"),
       
       conditionalPanel("input.map_subset=='enter'",
                        selectizeInput(inputId = "map_enterinput",
                                       label = "Select input",
                                       choices = NULL,
                                       multiple = TRUE,
                                       options = list(placeholder = 'enter names'))
                        ),
       
       conditionalPanel("input.map_subset=='upload'",
                        fileInput('map_file', 'Choose File Containing IDs\n(one row per ID)',
                                  accept=c('text/csv', 
                                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                           '.csv'))
```

Briefly, `selectizeInput` and `fileInput` input options are activated depending on the selected radioButton.

In the shiny application, there is a function which subsets the dataset based on the input selected by the `radioButton`.

```
 map_render(
    data_analy=data_analyzed,
    usesubset = input$map_subset == "enter")
```

Here i need `usesubset` argument to take the value of the choice made by `radioButton`

i.e. if the choice `enter` is selected then

```
map_render(
data_analy=data_analyzed,
usesubset = input$map_subset == "enter")
```

or if the choice `upload` is selected then

```
map_render(
    data_analy=data_analyzed,
    usesubset = input$map_subset == "upload")
```

Could someone offer help to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

`input$map_subset` would have the value of selected radiobutton.

Then this should work:

```
map_render(
    data_analy=data_analyzed,
    usesubset = input$map_subset)
```

Comment: that gives the error: `Error: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`

Comment: Perhaps it is value of subsequent inputs you are looking for:
`map_render(
    data_analy=data_analyzed,
    if (input$map_subset == "enter") usesubset = input$map_enterinput
else if (input$map_subset == "upload") usesubset = input$map_file
)`

Comment: the arguement `usesubset` is evaluated in a different code block as `if((usesubset)&(!is.null(subsetids))) {thesege = subsetids}`. is this the culprit?

Comment: For the error you are mentioning I found:
_"The specific error is caused by you using & to separate lines of code; this does not work because that is a logical operator in R. You could use ; instead or newline characters to separate lines."_
Is this perhaps your case? Does it give you also a line of the code where the error occurs?

Comment: The console shows                                                                                                     
 `115: map_subdat [fun.R#57]
  114: heatmap_data [fun.R#169]
  113: <reactive:HeatdatReactive_rna> [server.R#115]
   97: HeatdatReactive_rna
   96: renderText [server.R#337]`

Comment: `#57` corresponds to `if((usesubset)&(!is.null(subsetids))) {thesegenes = subsetids}`

Comment: `#169` corresponds to `tmpdat = map_subdat(...)`. the same functions which failed to execute `#57` block

Comment: and `server.R#115` is due to the error at `fun.R#169`. so the root source seem to be `[fun.R#57]` which is ` if((usesubset)&(!is.null(subsetids))) {thesege = subsetids}`

Comment: In `if((usesubset)&(!is.null(subsetids))) {thesegenes = subsetids}` `usesubset` is not type logical. Could that cause a problem?
You would need to test the value of `usesubset`.
Otherwise is hard to guess without seeing the code. Ideally you could extract it to reproducible code example..

Comment: `usesubset` is logical and set to `usesubset=FALSE`. Should this be changed?

Comment: Without seeing rest of the code (or reproducible example) I cannot judge.
In above code you tried to set the value to `usesubset` from the radiobutton input. So it is confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218272/discussion-between-chas-and-matushiq).